# vim error when included ctime header in another directory

Tags: vim, scope, time-t

**Here I got a strange error from vim when included ctime or time.h from a cpp file. I just copied a.cpp with these code in it:**

```
/* function:
 * date:
 * author:
 */
/* localtime example */
#include <ctime>
#include<iostream>

int main (int argc, char const* argv[]) {
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;

  time ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
  printf("current time is :%s",astime(timeinfo));

  return 0;
}
```

Then I open them in vim,here is the difference:

> if you see 403 Forbidden,just put cursor in the url input bar,press enter.

- open /home/hippo/cpps/cppworks/a.cpp in vim.(if you see 403 Forbidden,just put cursor in the url input bar,press enter.)

  http://photo21.hexun.com/p/2012/0927/485687/b_EA6D87DED1A027A1A21D8B31D0A5BB13.jpg
- open /home/hippo/a.cpp in vim come out all right

  http://photo21.hexun.com/p/2012/0927/485687/b_982DF55D2242797854727CA51824861E.jpg

So,I just cannot figure out the issue here from my ubuntu system.

I never met such strange issue when editing other file with other headers on my laptop.

My english is not good :<, but any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Find another image hosting service or embed the images in your question with Stackoverflow's editor's img button.

Comment: Thanks,and I think I figured it out.I created a header file /home/hippo/cpps/time.h with the same name "time.h" in the system directory.And vim  was calling this fake header instead of time.h in /usr/include/. I changed the name in the same directory and all things goes right! Any way thank you!

Answer (score 0):

there I would give my painful lesson from this issue.
Don't name a header file with the same name as the system headers!
Thanks any way!:)